# "Undefined symbols for architecture arm64" on extension

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsdata

My app builds fine, but now I'm attempting to build for Archive, and I'm getting this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "type metadata for (extension in TwIM):__ObjC.NSData.ImageType", referenced from:
      static TwIM.ImageCache.imagePath (imageURL : __ObjC.NSURL, imageType : (extension in TwIM):__ObjC.NSData.ImageType?) -> Swift.String? in ImageCache.o
      function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Owned To Guaranteed and Exploded> of static TwIM.ImageCache.imagePath (identifier : Swift.String, imageType : (extension in TwIM):__ObjC.NSData.ImageType?) -> Swift.String? in ImageCache.o
      function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Owned To Guaranteed and Exploded> of static TwIM.ImageCache.imageData (identifier : Swift.String, imageType : (extension in TwIM):__ObjC.NSData.ImageType?) -> __ObjC.NSData? in ImageCache.o
      function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Owned To Guaranteed and Exploded> of static TwIM.ImageCache.image (identifier : Swift.String, imageType : (extension in TwIM):__ObjC.NSData.ImageType?) -> Swift.AnyObject? in ImageCache.o
      function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Owned To Guaranteed, Arg[1] = Owned To Guaranteed and Exploded> of static TwIM.ImageCache.saveImage (imageData : __ObjC.NSData, identifier : Swift.String, imageType : (extension in TwIM):__ObjC.NSData.ImageType?) -> Swift.Bool in ImageCache.o
      function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Owned To Guaranteed and Exploded> of static TwIM.ImageCache.removeImage (identifier : Swift.String, imageType : (extension in TwIM):__ObjC.NSData.ImageType?) -> () in ImageCache.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What it's referring to is an extension I have on NSData, which includes an enum:

```
extension NSData {
  enum ImageType: String {
    case jpg = "jpg"
    case png = "png"
    case gif = "gif"
  }
}
```

I don't know why this would be causing an issue. I've cleaned, and cleared derived data as some people have suggested.

Comment: This error is faced when your library header is declaring some functions but the linker is unable to find them. You don't have the required library in your project or you didn't add the library path to library search Path.

Comment: Any ideas how I could troubleshoot that? Any steps I should take?

Comment: Did you pull that code from any other project? If yes, look for all the frameworks/libraries in that project and add them to yours. Don't forget to update the Library Search Path.

Comment: No, this is just an extension I have inside my own project, in a Swift file.

Answer (score 4):

Which Xcode and which Swift version do you use?

I first discovered this error message with Xcode 8 and Swift 3 beta 6. I had a look on what I imported but it was only Cocoa for all files. There were several errors of this kind, almost all belonging to a function, which was very large. The error only happens, if Global-Module-Optimization is selected, regardless if running or archiving.

So I divided this function in 6 smaller parts to look, which one was causing the problem. After making the function smaller, only two errors of this kind stayed. So I think it is a linker/optimizer-Problem in my case, because the code is the same, only divided in several small functions.

Please try to select Single-File-Optimization for Release and try to Archive. Does the error come again or are you successfull?

I guess, this will be not a problem in the final release.

Comment: Nope still a problem in the released version going to try your solution. Update: The fix works hmm did you report this bug to Apple?

Comment: No, I did not report this bug.

Comment: Has this problem in a function (granted, a long function), where the function was using a `let` (boolean) that was defined in global scope. Changing optimization (Target > Optimization Level) to Fast Single-File-Optimization solved that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting rid of the enum.  That's what fixed it for me.  Maybe there's a problem with enums in extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. And I solved this with following operations:
1. Go to build setting. 
2. Search for enable testablility. 
2. Set No for Debug.